# How can I alter pandas column data according to a specific condition based on a column entry?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have a data frame like this:

```
    MONTH   TIME     PATH    RATE
0    Feb  15:24:11  enp1s0  14.71Kb
```

I want to create a function which can identify if 'Kb' or 'Mb' is in the column RATE. If an entry in column RATE has 'Kb' or 'Mb' at the end, to strip it of 'Kb'/'Mb' and perform an operation to convert it into just b.
Here's my code so far where RATE is treated by the Dataframe as an object:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(listOfLists)
def strip(bytesData):
        if "Kb" in bytesData:
                bytesData/1000
        elif "Mb" in bytesData:
                bytesData/1000000

df['RATE']=df.apply(lambda x: strip(x['byteData']), axis=1)
```

How can I get it to change the value within the column while stripping it of unwanted characters and converting it into the format I need? I know once this operation is complete I'll have to change it to an int, however, I can't seem to alter the data in the way I need.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it be okay to make a new column that contains the byte value and then remove the RATE column after? Then you can rename the new column to be RATE again.

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be a multiplication instead of division?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your function a bit and use `map(lambda x:)` instead of apply, since we are working with a series, and not the full dataframe. Also I added some additional lines as to provide examples for both Kb and Mb and if neither are present:

```
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':[0,1,2,3],
                           'Time':['15:32','16:42','17:11','15:21'],
                           'Path':['xxxxx','yyyyy','zzzzz','aaaaa'],
                           'Rate':['14.71Kb','18.21Mb','19.01Kb','Error_1']})
def case_1(value):
  if value[-2:] == 'Kb':
    return float(value[:-2])*1000
  elif value[-2:] == 'Mb':
    return float(value[:-2])*100000
  else:
    return np.nan
example_df['Rate'] = example_df['Rate'].map(lambda x: case_1(x))
```

The logic for the function is, if it ends with `Kb` then multiply the value by 1000, else-if it ends with `Mb` multiply the value by 100000, otherwise simply return NaN (because neither of the two conditions are satisfied)
Output:

```
   Month   Time   Path       Rate
0      0  15:32  xxxxx    14710.0
1      1  16:42  yyyyy  1821000.0
2      2  17:11  zzzzz    19010.0
3      3  15:21  aaaaa        NaN
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to be of help, let me know if you need further help! Please feel free to accept my answer if it helped you solve the issue it will mark the question as solved, and help me with my reputation too!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative of how I may approach this. This solution handles other Abbreviations. It does rely on regex `re` standard lib package though.

This approach makes a new column called `Bytes`. I often find it helpful to keep the `RATE` column in this case to verify there aren't any edge cases I haven't thought of. I also use a mapping to obtain the necessary power to raise the value to to get the correct bytes. I did add the code required to drop the original `RATE` column and rename the new column.

```py
import re

def convert_to_bytes(contents):
    value, label, _ = re.split('([A-Za-z]+)', contents)
    factors = {'Kb': 1, 'Mb': 2, 'Gb': 3, 'Tb': 4}
    return float(value) * 1000**(factors[label])

df['Bytes'] = df['RATE'].map(convert_to_bytes)

# Drop original RATE column
df = df.drop('RATE', axis=1)
# Rename Bytes column to RATE
df = df.rename({'Bytes': 'RATE'}, axis='columns')
```

Comment: This a nice way of doing it too!

Comment: Thank you for this alternative!